# Mvc 4 bundling and base64 svg images

Tags: c#, .net, css, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I've been experiencing a problem with the Mvc4 bundling&minification feature when using embedded base64 svg images in the css.

Lets say I have a css rule like this:

```
url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94...<snip>...")
```

This works fine when bundling and minification is disabled. However, when it is enabled, that rule gets rewritten like this:

```
url("/content/style/data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94...<snip>...")
```

Breaking the url, since it's not a real URL but an embedded base64 image.

Anyone knows how to fix this, beside moving SVG images in standalone files?

Thanks.

Comment: That's weird, I am unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you include the css file in a bundle and then render it in the razord view through the @Styles.Render method?

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that.

Comment: Are you by chance using the beta1 release and the new CssRewriteUrlTransform?  That transform does not account for these kinds of urls

Comment: I'm using a less transformer. Could that be the culprit?

Comment: Yep that could do it as well, try it without that

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with using the Umbraco ClientDependancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just a bug on DotLess. We updated the nuget package and the problem went away.